# Bootstrap toggle chechkbox is not working when using it with html helper chechkboxfor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `@Html.CheckBoxFor` and trying to apply bootstrap class on this html helper but when I apply bootstrap class on this helper it become read-only. Can you please help me how I can submit 1 or 0 in db using MVC controller in DB.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsStreamProcessing, new { @class = "custom-control-input" } )
 <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Stream Processing</label>
```

Comment: Works fine. I don''t see what the problem is? I get a styled checkbox. Did you wrap it in `<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">` Also the id's do not match for the label `customSwitch1` and `IsStreamProcessing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using Bootstrap, I would suggest to use [Bootstrap Toggle](https://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) instead, it should works as expected:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.IsStreamProcessing, new { data_toggle = "toggle", 
                            data_onstyle = "success" })
```

However you need to reference the following:

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```